# Unable to see the File sent from controller on the browser in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a link in my View as below,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get Template", "GetTemplate", "MyController")
```

Controller Method as below,

```
public ActionResult GetTemplate()
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), "TestingThisNow.xlsx");
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                return File(path, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "TestingThisNow.xlsx");
            }
            return Content("file does not exist: " + path);
        }
```

The Files folder is part of my solution structure and it is there as a static file (as a template for data). I'm unable to figure out why it does not get served in the response with the above code.

When I do run it on IIS Express on my server I see it working and am presented with the option to open/save/save as but not from the version which I have deployed on my IIS on the machine. I do not see an exception as well.

I've tried several things and unable to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Do you have your file marked as "Content" in your .csproj file, so that it gets deployed when you publish your site? What sort of error are you getting? A 404 response?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Yes `<Content Include="Files\TestingThisNow.xlsx" />` I do not see any error. Nothing happens. I click on the link and i see the screen flicker once and thats it. Do I have to look at this from a permissions standpoint ?

Comment: Check out the Network area of your browser's dev tools. That should allow you to see what request is being made, and what it's returning. That might shed some more light on what's going on.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I just had the same URL opened on another machine here and see the download options. Strange as to why I dont see it. I see the response in Fiddler as well but do not see the prompt. So now I know the data is coming in but just that I do not see the prompt.

Comment: That is a somewhat unusual mime type. It's possible that the client-side simply know what to do with it, based on the version of browser and/or Office that the computer has installed. Were you able to verify that the response size is consistent with the expected file size? What happens if you change the headers to indicate the file should be downloaded instead of opened in the browser? Does the file download in a way that you can open it with excel on your machine afterward?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to add a MIME type record for .xlsx files in the web.config.

```
<configuration>

<system.webServer>

  <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xlsx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />

     </staticContent>

    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, since technically it isn't IIS serving this as a static file, but MVC streaming it.

Comment: This is not the problem. I restarted my machine and it started working.